# Why my Ajax UpdatePanel in not working to display a div element?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have a drop-down item in my sharepoint webpart and I want to query something and display it, so this means that i need to use `AutoPostBack=true` but i don't want to refresh the entire page. So i want to use Ajax UpdatePanel. If I try to display a label it works but if I want to display a DIV element it won't work. I have the following ascx code:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList2" runat="server" autopostback="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-Zgjidh Kompaninë">-- Zgjidh Kompaninë--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Meridian Corporation</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Meridian Express</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Buka</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
<asp:scriptmanagerproxy id="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"> 
</asp:scriptmanagerproxy>
<br />
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList2"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Comment: Can you please cross-check it using IE DOM in your page in browser that it is there or not?

Comment: Ok i will try it and i will let you know if it worked

Comment: @Hardik I have checked it and seems not to be there what should I do now any idea?

Comment: Please make the div **runat="server" ** & try again.

Comment: @Hardik no it is not working

Comment: @Hardik If you wish to help me I could share my screen, as same as you help me last time!

Comment: @Hardik I have Checked it via IE DOM the div is there but won't show anything!